# Create a list of all files in directory and subdirectories in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, python-2.7, directory-listing

I would like to come up with the most optimal way of listing all files in a directory and its subdirectories. Once done, I would like to filter them down.  So, optimally this would be done in 2 lines:

```
def getFilesContaining(filename):
    files = map(lambda x: os.path.join(x, file), os.walk('.')) #Note: this map does NOT work
    filtered_files = filter(lambda x: filename in x, files)
    return filtered_files
```

Comment: What does being 2 lines have to do with being optimal?

Answer (score 3):

```
def getFilesContaining(filename):
    paths = (os.path.join(root, f) for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.')
             for f in files) 
    return (path for path in paths if filename in path)
```

This returns an iterator. In your version, `filter` returns a list. If you really want a list, change the return value into a list comprehension by replacing the outer parentheses `(...)` into brackets `[...]`.

Comment: Awesome. This does exactly what I want.  In terms of efficiency, I'm not sure I like the triple for loop.  What's the difference in terms of efficiency of that loop versus something like os.system('find .')? Which would be more efficient?

Comment: Well, I just did a little experiment a 560MB directory and (not surprisingly) `os.system('find . -type f -name "*a*"')` was faster than `list(getFilesContaining('a'))`.